# Please identify the error (if any) in this test question

Tags: exam-questions, error

> No one was ready (A) / to help me to do it, (B) / but one of my college (C) / friends assisted me to do it (D) / No error (E)

Where is the error in the above sentence and what are the rules which make it incorrect?

Comment: This question will probably get closed because users don't like doing other people's homework. I suppose you could ask GPT and *maybe* you'd get an answer but there's no guarantee it will be correct. So, how about explaining to us why you're finding this sentence difficult? Which options would you immediately discard and why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Ankush please provide some details, for example where this question came from and which is the correct option in your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess arguably D? I would have said "assisted me **in doing** it" - "assist to" is more non-standard than "assist in". However, "assist to" would be used in many English dialects.